# WebDriverException: Error: write EPIPE

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

При попытке получить драйвер устройства выдаёт ошибку:

http://pastebin.com/UyJ2dduP

При выполнении
`new AndroidDriver(url, capabilities);`.
URL верный. Всё корректно работает на Mac OS X. Раньше работало и на Windows до обновления appium. Обновление проводил через `nmp install -g appium`. Запускаю сервер через `AppData\Roaming\npm\appium`. Сервер запускается корректно (проверка через url проходит).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме того, что должен быть указан `ANDROID_HOME` и в `PATH` должны быть прописаны пути до `platform_tools` и `tools`, в `PATH` также должен содержаться путь до самой SDK. Причём `%ANDROID_HOME%` не пойдёт. Нужен абсолютный путь.